# Python concatenacion de fecha en una consulta para mysql

Tags: mysql, python, python-2.7, date

Tengo la siguiente consulta mysql.

```
SELECT purchase.DATE, products.ID, products.NAME, purchase_details.UNITS, purchase.REFERENCE, purchase_details.PRICE,purchase.ID_PROVIDER
FROM purchase INNER JOIN (products INNER JOIN purchase_details ON products.ID = purchase_details.ID_PRODUCT) ON purchase.ID = purchase_details.ID_PURCHASE
WHERE (((purchase.DATE)>='2016-09-01 00:00:00' And (purchase.DATE)<='2016-09-28 23:59:59'))
order by purchase.date,products.NAME,purchase.reference
INTO OUTFILE
    '/tmp/ventas_descuento.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

La cual ocupo en un código de python para conectarme a una base de datos y extraer los datos en un csv, pero quiero que el usuario introduzca la fecha inicial y final y en base a estos parámetros obtener la data. Mi código de python es el siguiente:

```
import MySQLdb
import os
import os.path
import time

if os.path.exists("c:\\tmp\\"):
    print("ok,existe carpeta")
    try:
        os.system("del /F c:\\tmp\\reporte_compras.csv")
    except:
        pass
else:
    os.mkdir("c:\\tmp")
bd = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","root","1234","puntoventa",port=3306)
cursor = bd.cursor()
query="""SELECT purchase.DATE, products.ID, products.NAME, purchase_details.UNITS, purchase.REFERENCE, purchase_details.PRICE,purchase.ID_PROVIDER
        FROM purchase INNER JOIN (products INNER JOIN purchase_details ON products.ID = purchase_details.ID_PRODUCT) ON purchase.ID = purchase_details.ID_PURCHASE
        WHERE (((purchase.DATE)>='2016-09-01 00:00:00' And (purchase.DATE)<='2016-09-28 23:59:59'))
        order by purchase.date,products.NAME,purchase.reference
        INTO OUTFILE
                '/tmp/ventas_descuento.csv'
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"""
try:
   cursor.execute(query)

except:
   print "Error: No se pudo obtener la data"

bd.close()
os.system('cls')
archivo = open("c:/tmp/reporte_compras.csv","r")
lista= archivo.read()
archivo.close()
#Pongo encabezados
lista2="FECHA,CODIGO,PRODUCTO,UNIDADES,FACTURA,PRECIOCOMPRA,PROVEEDOR   \n"
lista3=lista2 + lista
archivo = open("c:/tmp/reporte_compras.csv","w")
archivo.write(lista3)
archivo.close()
print "Listo reporte de ventas por producto incluyendo descuento exportado a c:/tmp/reporte_compras.csv"
os.system('pause')
os.system("explorer c:\\tmp\\")
```

Ya intenté concatenando con variables de string línea por línea en la construcción del query, pero no funcionó, el siguiente codigo es el que utilice para construir la consulta con las fechas dadas por el usuario.

```
    cadena="SELECT tickets.TICKETID, receipts.DATENEW, products.NAME, products.PRICESELL, payments.PAYMENT, ticketlines.PRICE, products.pricesell-ticketlines.price,(products.pricesell-ticketlines.price)/products.pricesell"
    separador="\n"
    cadena2="FROM taxes INNER JOIN ((((receipts INNER JOIN tickets ON receipts.ID = tickets.ID) INNER JOIN (products INNER JOIN ticketlines ON products.ID = ticketlines.PRODUCT) ON receipts.ID = ticketlines.TICKET) INNER JOIN payments ON receipts.ID = payments.RECEIPT) INNER JOIN taxlines ON receipts.ID = taxlines.RECEIPT) ON (taxes.ID = ticketlines.TAXID) AND (taxes.ID = taxlines.TAXID)"
    cadena3="WHERE (((receipts.DATENEW)>='"
    cadena4="' And (receipts.DATENEW)<='"
    cadena5="\'))"
    cadena6="order by tickets.TICKETID, receipts.DATENEW"
    cadena7="""INTO OUTFILE
            '/tmp/ventas_descuento.csv'
            FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
            OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';"""
    abrir="\"\"\""
    fechain=raw_input ("Introduce fecha inicial en formato AAAA-MM-DD: ")
    fechafin=raw_input ("Introduce fecha final en formato AAAA-MM-DD: ")
    horain="00:00:00"
    horafin="23:59:59"
    fechahorain=(fechain+" "+horain)
    fechahorafin=(fechafin+" "+horafin)
    query=(abrir+cadena+separador+cadena2+separador+cadena3+fechahorain+cadena4+fechahorafin+cadena5+separador+cadena6+separador+cadena7+abrir)
```

Comment: *Ya intenté concatenando con variables de string línea por línea en la construcción del query, pero no funcionó*: Aun así, sería bueno que compartas tu intento para que recibas ayuda mas específica. Si entiendo bien, el codigo que está en tu pregunta no es el intento.

Comment: Muchas gracias pro la pronta respuesta, mira intente agregando cada linea de codigo de mysql a 7 variables, con 2 raw_input pido las fecha inicio y fina, por ultimo  concatenando todo el texto lo pego al final del primero codigo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba usando `format`

```
fechain=raw_input("Introduce fecha inicial en formato AAAA-MM-DD: ")
fechafin=raw_input("Introduce fecha final en formato AAAA-MM-DD: ")

query="""SELECT purchase.DATE, products.ID, products.NAME, purchase_details.UNITS, purchase.REFERENCE, purchase_details.PRICE,purchase.ID_PROVIDER
        FROM purchase INNER JOIN (products INNER JOIN purchase_details ON products.ID = purchase_details.ID_PRODUCT) ON purchase.ID = purchase_details.ID_PURCHASE
        WHERE (((purchase.DATE)>='{0} 00:00:00' And (purchase.DATE)<='{1} 23:59:59'))
        order by purchase.date,products.NAME,purchase.reference
        INTO OUTFILE
                '/tmp/ventas_descuento.csv'
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
                OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"'
                LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';""".format(fechain, fechafin)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono a la perfeccion!